# joins in oracle cursor

Tags: oracle, join, cursor

I am trying to use a join in oracle cursor, which it is failing. Can anybody give me some help to fix below cursor. Is it possible to use joins in oracle cursor??

```
CURSOR items_cursor IS
    SELECT a.*, b.* FROM  
    ( SELECT DataId, Name, VersionNum, OwnerId, SubType, LEVEL Lev FROM DTree 
      START WITH ParentId = 2000 CONNECT BY PRIOR DataId= ABS(ParentId)
    )a, 
    (                  
     SELECT o.DataId, o.Permissions OwnerPerm, p.Permissions PublicPerm FROM DTreeAcl o, DTreeAcl p WHERE
     o.DataId=p.Dataid AND o.AclType=1 AND p.AclType=3 AND (o.Permissions != 130 OR p.Permissions != 36995)
    )b        
    WHERE a.Lev >= 1 AND a.Lev <= 3 AND a.DataId = b.DataId;
```

Above query works fine without cursor.

This cursor in then using in for loop.

```
BEGIN                   
 FOR item IN items_cursor LOOP
 rowCnt := rowCnt + 1;  
  -- Some update and insert stmts             
 IF rowCnt = 1000 THEN
  COMMIT;rowCnt := 0;
 END IF;               
 END LOOP;
```

Here is my full procedure code..

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "RMNAUSR"."PERMS_UPDATE_UPTO_LEVEL3" IS
rowCnt INT := 0;
ownerPerm INT := 130;
publicPerm INT := 36995;
permUpdated BOOLEAN:= FALSE;
excludeSubTypes VARCHAR(30) := '201,202,203';

CURSOR items_cursor IS
        (SELECT a.*, b.* FROM  
        ( SELECT DataId, Name, VersionNum, OwnerId, SubType, LEVEL Lev FROM DTree 
          START WITH ParentId = 2000 CONNECT BY PRIOR DataId= ABS(ParentId)
        )a, 
        (                  
         SELECT o.DataId, o.Permissions OwnerPerm, p.Permissions PublicPerm FROM DTreeAcl o, DTreeAcl p WHERE
         o.DataId=p.Dataid AND o.AclType=1 AND p.AclType=3 AND (o.Permissions != 130 OR p.Permissions != 36995)
        )b        
        WHERE a.Lev >= 1 AND a.Lev <= 3 AND a.DataId = b.DataId);

BEGIN                   
        FOR item IN items_cursor LOOP
             rowCnt := rowCnt + 1;  
             permUpdated := FALSE;
                -- some insert and update stmts here
             IF rowCnt = 1000 THEN
                     COMMIT;
                     rowCnt := 0;
             END IF;               
      END LOOP;

      COMMIT;
      EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN raise_application_error(-20001,SQLERRM);
END PERMS_UPDATE_UPTO_LEVEL3;
```

Thanks in Adavance!!
Arun

Comment: It is certainly possible to use joins with an Oracle cursor -- what specifically is failing?

Comment: i am not getting any specific or understandable error msg. I'm using DBVisualizer and it returns the below msg>    11:34:33  [@CALL - 0 row(s), 0.000 secs]  [Error Code: 6550, SQL State: 65000]  ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00905: object RMNAUSR.PERMS_UPDATE_UPTO_LEVEL3 is invalid
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored

Comment: Sounds like there is a problem elsewhere in the stored procedure containing the cursor.

Comment: Is the procedure/function/package the cursor is in compiled cleanly? The error suggests not. Try doing `show errors procedure RMNAUSR.PERMS_UPDATE_UPTO_LEVEL3`, or whatever object type it is part of; or just `show errors` after trying to create it.

Comment: i tired without backets. But still no success

Comment: Yeah, I checked and that's fine, just looks odd, sorry. So what error(s) did you get when you compiled - did you run `show errors`?

Comment: how to specify show errors? i'm calling this procedure like this: @call PERMS_UPDATE_UPTO_LEVEL3(); I am using DBVisualizer

Comment: It isn't the call that's the problem. When you run the `create or replace procedure ...` command, where do you execute that? If it's in SQL*Plus or SQL Developer then do `show errors` immediately after that, as I said before. If it's somewhere else then that will have some mechanism to report failure or show errors, possibly on right-click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd have two columns projected from the query with the name DATAID -- try aliasing the name of one of them.

Comment: i tired by modifying like this **`SELECT a.DataId, a.Name, a.VersionNum, a.OwnerId, a.SubType, a.Lev, b.DataId,b.OwnerPerm,b.PublicPerm FROM...`**  but no success

Comment: @Arun - you still have two columns called `DataId`; you need to alias one of them, e.g. `..., b.DataID as DataIdB, ...`